# How to create a menu with language in Hugo

Tags: hugo

I want to create a menu just like "Categories" and "Tags" but with languageCode

I tried just add this to menu: main:

```
- identifier: Language
          name: Language
          url: /language/
          weight: 3
```

and create content/language.md

```
---
title: "language"
layout: "language"
url: "/language/"
summary: language
---
```

but it ends up being a page like this [image]

pls help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Maybe you need to add more information, like how you want the output to look, what theme you are using, etc.

Currently, you are simply creating a new page called "Language" and this is exactly what you can see on your output. It seems to me that you lack fundamental knowledge of how Hugo works. You should consider taking a look at the Hugo documentation at https://gohugo.io/documentation/ and learn the basics. I would recommend reading the "Getting started" and "Content management" chapters.